# How do I implement a unary operator overload for a forward declared type in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, operator-overloading, forward-declaration, unary-operator

The following code does not compile in Visual Studio 2008. How do I get it to allow a unary operator in the Foo1 class that converts it to a Bar, when Foo1 is defined before Bar?

```
class Foo1
{
public:
    int val;

    operator struct Bar() const;
};

struct Bar
{
    int val;
};

// This does not compile
Foo1::operator Bar() const
{
    Bar x;
    x.val = val;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to have `struct Bar`, C++'s structs are types already.

Comment: I'm using struct Bar as a forward declaration, since the definition of Bar doesn't appear until later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. There are two solutions:

```
struct Bar;

class Foo1
{
public:
    int val;

    operator struct Bar() const;
};
```

Or:

```
class Foo1
{
    typedef struct Bar MyBar;
public:
    int val;

    operator MyBar() const;
};
```

(The operator::Bar() implementation remains unchanged)

Comment: It doesn't look like a solution wrt C++, but rather like a workaround for a compiler bug.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could:

```
//forward declaration of Bar
struct Bar;

class Foo1
{
public:
    int val;

    operator Bar() const;
};

struct Bar
{
    int val;
};

//Now it should compile
Foo1::operator Bar() const
{
    Bar x;
    x.val = val;
    return x;
}
```